Finding mistake in contour integral. $f(z)=\frac{\exp{(-1+i)z}}{z \cdot z^{1/2}}$
I'm trying to calculate the following real integral:
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\sin{t}}{t^{3/2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}.$$
I tried defining the complex function:
$$f(z)=\frac{\exp{(-1+i)z}}{z \cdot z^{1/2}},$$
which should be holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}_0^{-}$, when working with the main branch cut of the square root (the argument goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$). I have considered the following contour:


I call the integral over the real line $C+iS$. $C$ and $S$ are equal to:
$$C = \int_{\varepsilon}^{R}\frac{e^{-t}\cos{t}}{t^{3/2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$S = \int_{\varepsilon}^{R}\frac{e^{-t}\sin{t}}{t^{3/2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}$$
The integral in the big circle vanishes as $R \to \infty$ because the real part in the exponential is negative, also, the denominator is of order $R^{3/2}$ while the length of the curve is of order $R$.
The integral over the imaginary line can be solved substituting $z=it, t \in [R,\varepsilon]$. The value I obtained is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)(C-iS)$.
Finally, the integral of the inner circle is solved substituting $z=\varepsilon e^{it}, t \in [\pi/2, 0]$. I found:
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\frac{\exp{((-1+i)\varepsilon e^{it}) }}{e^{it}\cdot e^{it/2}\cdot \varepsilon^{3/2}}i \varepsilon e^{it}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}(-2+\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}) + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\varepsilon})$$

Now, the function is holomorphic in an open set containing the contour. So the sum of all these integrals should be $0$. Solving for $S$ and $C$, I find that $S=0$, which is wrong. It should be something positive, according to numerical calculators online. But I cannot find the error. I appreciate any help, thank you in advance :)
EDIT: I found the mistake. It was at the very last step, when solving the obtained equation:
$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)(C-iS)+C+iS+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}(-2+\sqrt{2}-i\sqrt{2}) + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\varepsilon}) = 0.$$
The real and imaginary parts of this equation are actually linearly dependent, so one can only find this relationship between $C$ and $S$:
$$C+(\sqrt{2}+1)S = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}} + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\varepsilon}),$$
which I have checked for low values of $\varepsilon$ and seems correct. So $S$ or $I$ can't be obtained using (only) this contour.

I'm not convinced you can recover $I$ when you equate the imaginary part and the limit as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ on both sides of $0 = \text{the integrals over each curve}$. When you evaluate the integral of the inner circle in terms of the $\operatorname{erf}$ function, there's this pesky $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ in a denominator that doesn't get canceled out. Numerically, it seems like $|f(z)|$ near $z=0$ is extremely huge. This might help.

@Accelerator thanks for responding. I don’t think that should be a problem, the function is well defined in the considered domain for each $\varepsilon>0$. Another thing is the behaviour of the real and imaginary parts when taking $\varepsilon \to 0$. While the real part must blow up because $t^{-3/2}$ is not integrable near $t=0$, the imaginary part should actually converge to the well defined value it has when $\varepsilon=0$, because $t^{-1/2}$ is integrable. But instead it seems to converge to $0$.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\sin{t}}{t^{3/2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}=\sqrt{2 (\sqrt{2}-1)\pi}$$
See also WolframAlpha
